# Be + infinitive /has have to

Tags: british-english

I would like to know if these structures share the same meaning:

> If I were to do it, I would...
>
> If I had to do it,I Would...
>
> you are to finish doing the Washin up by..
>
> you have to finish...

These are examples.

Answer (score 1):

"If I were to" sounds like a like a choice ("If I chose to"), while "If I had to" sounds like a requirement ("If I must").

Because the third and forth examples start with "you", they both sound like demands being made of someone. If the third example has instead been "I am finishing", it would not imply whether were forced to do it, just that you were doing it.